# How to initialize ConnectionStrings collection in NUnit

Tags: asp.net, nunit, web-config, automated-tests

I want to test ASP.NET application using NUnit, but it seems WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings collection is empty when running from NUnit GUI.

Could you tell me how to initialize this collection (probably in [SetUp] function of [TestFixture])? Should I copy Web.config somethere?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have your unit-test assembly named Company.Component.Tests.dll, then just make sure that Company.Component.Tests.dll.config is there with the proper connection string.

Additionally, it might be a good idea to decouple your connection provider class from the configuration, so that you will have flexibility in persistence (i.e.: switching from *.config to something else) and easier testing.

Also check out "[How NUnit Finds Config Files](http://nunit.com/blogs/?p=9)"

Comment: When I followed that link: "How NUnit Finds Config Files" I got an error from the web server: "Error Establishing Database Connection".  Kind of ironic/funny coming from the context of this question =P

Answer (score 9):

### NUnit .config file location depends on how you created the NUnit project file

Where .config files for NUnit tests are located is a little bit more complicated than other posts here suggest. There are settings for this in the NUnit GUI Project/Edit dialogue. The default values all depend upon how you created your NUnit project file.

When you open the NUnit GUI and select File/Open and then select a .dll file a new project gets set up with settings to look for a config file with the same name as the dll in the same directory. So if you loaded `\bin\debug\MyTests.dll` NUnit looks for `\bin\Debug\MyTests.dll.config` by default. The only trouble with this is that when you create a release build you need to create a separate NUnit project.

If you have created the NUnit project by selecting File/NewProject then the default setting is to look for a config file with the same name as the NUnit project. So if you created `\MyNUnitProject.nunit` NUnit looks for `\MyNUnitProject.config` by default.

The chances are you have used Visual Studio to create an `\App.config` file and stuck it in the source folder for your test dll. When you buld your test project this gets copied to `\bin\Debug\MyTests.dll.config` or `\bin\Release\MyTests.dll.config` depending upon the configuration you have selected. If you have opened the MyTest.dll directly in NUnit this will work fine, however if you have created a new NUnit project you’re in trouble as it will not look for these files by default.

To resolve the issue you need to open up the Project/Edit dialog in the NUnit GUI and check that you have two Configurations Debug & Release to match your .Net project. Once you have done this you can select the Debug Configuration and set the ApplicationBase to `bin\Debug\` and set the Configuration File Name to `MyTests.dll.config`. Do the same for the Release configuration and away you go.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the app.config for libraries (where I assume your tests are) and put them in there.